# Why does Java allow a proxy class to be checked-cast to a declared type but not a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, casting, proxy

Fairly simple question...

```
private static <R extends Runnable> void test(R r, Class<R> rClass) {
    //Assume invocation handlers ih1, ih2, ih3 already declared

    //Example 1: Checked-cast to declared type specified as interface
    Runnable x = (Runnable) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Runnable.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{Runnable.class}, ih1); //No warning

    //Example 2: Checked-cast to declared type not specified as interface
    String y = (String) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Runnable.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{Runnable.class}, ih2); //No warning at compile-time, even though String does not implement Runnable (I would imagine this would fail at runtime, although I haven't tried it)

    //Example 3: Cast to generic type
    R z = (R) Proxy.newProxyInstance(rClass, new Class[]{rClass}, ih3); //Unchecked cast warning
}
```

`Proxy.newProxyInstance` returns an object of type `Object`, so it seems there is some magic somewhere which tells the compiler that it's safe to cast this object to any declared type. This doesn't make sense to me (even the JavaDoc for proxy classes only says that a proxy can be safely cast to one of its own interface types) and leads to some strange behaviour as per example 2 above. However, this same "magic" does not give the same safe result for generic types.

Is there any way around this if you want to proxy a generic type, other than "suppress warnings"?

Comment: _I would imagine this would fail at runtime_ Yes.

Comment: There's no magic in the compiler -- it's just that a cast to `(String)` can be checked at runtime, which makes any possible failure super easy to debug. A cast to `(R)` can't be checked at runtime due to erasure, which can make it very hard to figure out where a wrong object came from.

Comment: `Proxy.newProxyInstance` is just a method with a return type. The compiler doesn't care what its implementation does. It trusts that you know.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood unchecked casts. I thought that unchecked cast warnings occurred for all casts to a more specific type, however it seems they only occur for casts involving generic types.

Comment: Go through some of the rules [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2).